# How to check if dropdown list values matches with table country list in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have dropdownlist for country where it contains 6 countries. But I have a country table as well where I have more than 100 countries.

Now I want to check whether `CountryId` exists in dropdown list or not. If  `CountryId` does not exists then by default choose first from dropdown list.

Any help is highly appreciated. Please show the way to do this?

Model

```
public int? Country { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountriesList { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
   var country = db.Country.SingleOrDefault(u => u.CountryId == user.CountryID)              
       int CountryId = countrylist.CountryId;


          CountriesList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
             new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "India" },
             new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Pakistan" },
             new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Nepal" },
             new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "Sri Lanka" },
             new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "Bangladesh" },
             new SelectListItem {Value = "6", Text = "Bhutan" },

            }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountriesList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `Country` property value of your view model to the country id, the helper will select the corresponding option when the SELECT element is rendered.

You can check the specific countryId value exist in the `CountriesList` property of your view model using the `Any` method.

The `SingleOrDefault` method will return `NULL` when there are no records matching your where condition. So do a null check on that as well.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var vm = new CreateVm();
    vm.CountriesList = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
     new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "India" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Pakistan" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Nepal" },
     new SelectListItem {Value = "4", Text = "Sri Lanka" },
     new SelectListItem { Value = "5", Text = "Bangladesh" },
     new SelectListItem {Value = "6", Text = "Bhutan" }    
    };

    // user object is intstantiated somehave
    var country = db.Country.SingleOrDefault(u => u.CountryId == user.CountryID);

    if (country != null && vm.CountriesList
                           .Any(a => a.Value == country.CountryId.ToString()))
    {
         vm.Country = country.CountryId;
    }
    else
    {
         vm.Country = 1;  // Value of "India" option (select list)item
    }
    return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Shyju. Great help!